# Dice Rolling Probability matrix with a D20(20 sided-dice)

Tags: r, matrix, dice

I am trying to run dice rolling simulations in R. In my project I am using the Dungeons and Dragon's D20, which is a 20 sided die that is used in table top games like .

One of the features of the game is when a player is attacking or casting spells, they roll the D20 and the outcome of the roll determines success. Players may have positive or negative modifiers to add to the sum of the roll. I am trying to create a of a player rolling a particular result based on their modifier. This is what I have so far:

```
D20_prob = function(d, nreps) {
roll = matrix(sample(20, size = d * nreps, replace = T), ncol = nreps)
  result_tot = (roll + 1) # Adds modifier
  return(prop.table(table(result_tot)))
}
```

`D20_prob(1, 100)`

And it results in something like this:

```
   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21 
0.02 0.04 0.04 0.02 0.10 0.08 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.03 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.06 0.05 0.05 0.08 0.04 0.06 0.07
```

In the game of D&D modifiers can range from -5 to +5. Can any one help me modify my code so I can create a table that ranges -5 to +5?

Comment: Is there any reason for not computing the theoretical probabilities instead of a random sample?

Comment: I would much prefer that! I just don't know how via R? Computing the theoretical probabilities would greatly increase the value of my project so if you know how to do that greatly appreciated

Comment: @KeithSanders Aren't the theoretical probabilities trivial? The die is assumed to be unbiased, so unless there is some unspecified probability distribution on the modifiers that you want to take into account, the probability is 1/20 for any possible number (with the sole role of the modifiers being in determining which numbers are possible -- but that is just an addition or subtraction). There is little point in generating a table when everything in that table is the same number (0.05). All this makes me wonder if you intended to ask a different question. Perhaps you can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you want is

```
sample.int(10, n= 20, replace = TRUE)
```

It really depends what you want to simulate. 
If you want to see how probable a result is, given a certain amount of rolls (i.e if I use that modifier is it better than another given the damage I do in next twenty hours of play), here you would use the above mentioned function and simulate as many rolls as you can (i.e 1000 or more). 
The second option is you want to see the probability of a result in general (i.e. if I need to roll above 18 what is the chance of me rolling that). In that case the probability of rolling a number is 1/20 since you have a D20.

I once did a similar thing: My simulator was done with random rolls to see how likely a combination is successful to give players an idea how their modifiers will work in the long run.
But in that case be aware that random numbers never are truly random (there are better and worse packages).

Edit:

To loop through the damages you can use a for loop:

```
 for (modifier in -5:5){
  result_tot = prop.table(table(roll + modifier))
}
```

The problem is I have never worked with data.tables and I do not seem to be able to merge all the different tables which are generated. In the example above each loop overwrites the table result_tot. So you need to print it before or find a way to merge the resulting tables.

Comment: Im not sure I understand or if my question is clear. The part I really want to focus on is the modifiers in the part of the code that has: result_tot = (roll + 1).

 When I run the code it gives me a table that has the results of the +1 modifier result. Is there a way I can generate a table that has modifiers -5 to +5 all in one code or would I have to manual change the modifiers and each time? Also can you share more about your simulator? It seems fascinating.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question. I edited it above. My simulator was a basic html page with a graph on how much damage a certain combination would make in the long run. So you could add modifiers, bonuses etc and see how many times you would do how much damage. And with which rolls. It was mostly for game developers whi wanted to see how to balance their systems. But could be used by power gamers as well ;)